# Homework Beginner C++: Unable to perform Type Casting during addition of integers

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In order to help us understand type casting in C++, we are required to perform addition of two `int`'s as shown below. If we provide two `int`'s as `4` and `5` respectively, the output should be `4 + 5 = 9`.

I tried to follow [this type casting tutorial](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/) without any success. Could someone please provide me a hint or something?

Quoting the assignment verbatim.

> Your friend wrote a program called an adder. The adder is supposed to take two numbers inputted by a user and then find the sum of those numbers, but it’s behaving oddly.
>
> Your first task is to figure out what is wrong with the adder. Your second task is to fix it.
>
> Hint(s) to identify the problem
> Try entering 1 and 1. You expect the output to be 2 but you get 11 instead. Similarly, if you enter 3 and 4, you expect the output to be 7 but you get 34. Remember, string concatenation also uses the + operator.
>
> Hint(s) to identify the solution
> The + operator functions differently based on the type of data that comes before and after it. What data types will cause the + operator to calculate a mathematical sum? What data type is present in the program now? How do you convert from one data type to another? Check out the Type Casting page for some idea

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  string num1;
  string num2;
  cout << "Type the first whole number and then press Enter or Return: ";
  cin >> num1;
  cout << "Type the second whole number and then press Enter or Return: ";
  cin >> num2;
  

  string sum = num1 + num2;
  cout << ( num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + sum )  << endl;

  
  return 0;
  
}
```

Comment: [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Why your variables are all strings when your task requires that these are ints?

Comment: My task requires me to do a type conversion at the end

Comment: What kind of type conversion? Please quote your assignment verbatim.

Comment: Sure. I will edit the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you typecast a character or string it get's converted  into its equivalent ASCII value , either you need to use stoi or subtract from '0' for every digit position(a bit repeatitive work) go with stoi

Comment: You can't typecast a whole string, and simply subtracting `'0'` from each character in a string is not enough to produce an equivalent integer of correct value. `stoi()` will work, but really this is not the best solution for this task. So I question why this was marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: if you extract every digit position and subtract from '0' , you get a numerical value and it's a simple logic to understand how to reconstruct the entire string into a number :) (that's why i denoted it as repeatitve work)

Comment: Still not a good solution for the task given

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the code is that it is performing **string concatenation** when it needs to perform **arithmetic addition** instead. So you need to get the user's input into numeric variables, not strings. The assignment even alludes to this.

However:

> Check out the Type Casting page for some idea

That is bad advice for this task, as you can't solve the problem with **type casting**.

You need to either:

- Change the code to use `int` variables instead of `string` variables. This is the preferred solution, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  int num1;
  int num2;
  cout << "Type the first whole number and then press Enter or Return: ";
  cin >> num1;
  cout << "Type the second whole number and then press Enter or Return: ";
  cin >> num2;

  int sum = num1 + num2;
  cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << sum << endl;

  return 0;
  
}
```

- Otherwise, if you want to continue using `string` variables, you need to **convert** (not **type cast**!) their values into `int` values at runtime, and then convert back afterwards, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  string num1;
  string num2;
  cout << "Type the first whole number and then press Enter or Return: ";
  cin >> num1;
  cout << "Type the second whole number and then press Enter or Return: ";
  cin >> num2;

  int sum = stoi(num1) + stoi(num2);
  cout << ( num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + to_string(sum) )  << endl;

  return 0;
  
}
```